# Разделить список на два

Tags: python

Дан список, состоящий из N целочисленных элементов, вводится с клавиатуры. Как переписать все положительные элементы в другой список, а остальные - в третий?

Comment: а что новичок сделал, чтобы помочь себе самому?

Comment: все просто - запрашиваете ввод чисел, числа заносятся в список, а затем фильтруете этот список. Все! Почитайте в инете что-нибудь.

Answer (score 4):

https://ideone.com/dy1KdU

```
a = map(int, input().split())

ok = []
no = []

for x in a:
  (ok if x > 0 else no).append(x)
  
print(ok)
print(no)
```